# No internet connection after using boot-repair

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, boot-repair

I have problems with my internet connection after using boot-repair. 
Wi-fi connected but can not be used even cannot be seen in ifconfig

Comment: can you connect using Ethernet cable ?